# How to add new OPERATION in VIEWS 3.x using DRUPAL 7

Tags: views, 7

I'm looking for the Drupal way to add a new custom `Operation` in the list of **OPERATIONS** available at the Views admin/structure/views

PS: This is not at all related to [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations)

[image: Operations in Views]